# auto complete "on fly" and select fast any command

Tags: completion

windows 10, emacs 26.1,

```
M-x occur
```

[image]

And if want to execute, e.g. command "`occur-mode`" I need to

1. Press `-`
2. Press `TAB`
3. Input `mode`

OK, it's work. But it not very conveniently. Is it possible to run command `occur-mode` faster? Maybe has some package for this?

P.S. I know about **helm** package. But I don't like it.

Comment: If you don't like helm you might prefer `ivy` or `ido`. Also check out `smex` (which uses ido by default but can be used with ivy). And most of these packages can take advantage of `flx` for fuzzy matching - there are lots of options here, you may need to experiment to find what works best for you.

Comment: Also, just because I'm curious: Are you really trying to run the command `occur-mode`? It would be much more common to run `occur`, which will open its results in a buffer that is already in occur-mode. And in that case I'd recommend learning the key bindings and using `M-s o` to do an occur search.

Answer (score 2):

Use `icomplete-mode` - the builtin incremental minibuffer completion mode. It continuously displays a list of possible completions as soon as you type in minibuffer. Then `M-x oc-m` and `C-j` to accept completion candidate.

Comment: icomplete-mode not exist in MELPA repo. Where I can download it?

Comment: @a_subscriber `icomplete-mode` probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.29. So just turn it on with e.g. `M-x icomplete-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make your recipe a bit shorter: `M-x occur-m TAB` (or even `M-x oc-m TAB`). And you can of course hit `TAB` at any point, to see completions of what you've typed so far - e.g., `M-x oc TAB`.
2. If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can show completions as you type. Icicles calls this [incremental completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion#IncrementalCompletion).

   The behavior is controlled by option `icicle-incremental-completion`. By default this does not kick in unless `*Completions*` is already displayed (hit `TAB` to display it). But if you customize the option to a non-`nil`, non-`t` value then it kicks in as soon as you type. Then, as soon as you type `M-x o` you see completions for `o`; when you type `M-x oc` you see completions for that, etc.

   There are also options for the delay before incremental completion kicks in (`icicle-incremental-completion-delay`) and the number of completions needed for it to kick in (`icicle-incremental-completion-threshold`).

Comment: I set icicle-incremental-completion = Update ‘*Completions*’ incrementally if already displayed. Restart Emacs. But when I type "occur" nothing happend. *Completions* not show.

Comment: That's the default value (`t`). Set it to `Update ‘*Completions*’ incrementally always` (`always`) if you want `*Completions*` to show as soon as you type something. No need to restart Emacs. (But you need to turn on `icy-mode`, of course.)